# DataGrid within a ComboBoxItem not taking full size

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have the following ComboBox code:

```
<ComboBox>
                            <ComboBoxItem>
                                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" />
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" />
                                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                                </DataGrid>
                            </ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
```

When the ComboBox with is long and the text of the DataGrid columns is short, you could see the background of the ComboBoxItem when the ComboBox is opened. Is there a way to make the DataGrid fill the entire space of the ComboBoxItem?

Comment: did you try binding the width of DataGrid to ActualWidth of ComboBoxItem?

Comment: I tried that but the result is the DataGrid disappearing when the ComboBoxItem is opened.